# Unable to set Date Format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to collect a date from text boxes and then do a comparison on them.  I am entering the dates in `dd-MM-yyyy` format, however when the comparison is running its running is in a `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

[my fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/3ut8a7zj/)

in my live application I am using a bootstrap datepicker to enter the date so the date entered will always be the correct format.

Ive looked here at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) and I have also tried looking at

```
var dt1  = d1.split(/\-|\s/)
var dt2  = d2.split(/\-|\s/)
dat1 = new Date(dt1);
dat2 = new Date(dt2);
dat1.format("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

but this also fails.

Any and all help very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: The `Date` constructor does not accept arrays as parameter!

Comment: I mean, it'll just cast it to string in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getTime()` method if you want to make comparison on dates :

```
if(dat1.getTime() > dat2.getTime()) { ... }
```

On your example :  https://jsfiddle.net/3ut8a7zj/1/

Comment: Although its not in the format I am looking for it still works thank you